# silverlight -how to install

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight-3.0, installation

please I can't able to install the silverlight on vs2008.please tell me how to install
silverlight on vs2008. give me step by step description otherwise  any most preferable link
for that I am going in correct way.& how the controls are to be in vs2008.
& also me give a beginner example for that i can start to teach the silvelight.

please!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the steps mentioned [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=293&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).

Answer (score 0):

Visit [the official site](http://silverlight.net/getstarted/), and follow the instructions....

For good beginner examples, check the site mentioned above, or visit [Scott Guthrie's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/), he has a whole bunch of posts on the subject.